# Converting bin in int etc. [python]

Tags: python, numbers, decimal, converters

I made a program that is supposed to convert **binary** numbers to **decimal**.
The user is asked to enter a number, there is a boolean check for looking up if thats an bin number, if thats the case it supposed to convert bin to decimal number.
Problem: I get an error *invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b11001'*

Code:

```
def binToDec(n):
    return int(n)


def Umwandlung():
    n = input("Eine Zahl eingeben: ")
    if type(n)==str:
        binToDec(n)
    else:
        return "Nicht moeglich"
```

Comment: Note that `type(n)` is always `str` when reading from `input()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `int(n)` to `int(n, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the most pythonic way is to put it in a `try ... except` block and catch the ValueError:

```
n = input("Eine Zahl eingeben: ")
try:
    print(int(n, 2))
except ValueError:
    print("Nicht möglich")
```